# How can I unignore a Mercurial folder?

Tags: mercurial

I ignored a folder called "temp", how can I unignore it and resume tracking it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If temp is empty, Mercurial only tracks files. Otherwise, something is ignoring it in your .hgignore. You could be ignoring a pattern that matches directories above temp, or all the files or directories below temp.

Comment: It contains folders inside.

Comment: More empty folders?  Again, Mercurial only tracks files.

Answer (score 1):

take it out of your .hgignore file and it should start tracking it again.  I've had troubles the other way where I have something in hg I want to ignore. It seems you have to delete the file out of source control, then .hgignore is followed.

Comment: It's not mentioned at all in my .hgignore!

Comment: If `temp` is empty, Mercurial only tracks files.  Otherwise, something is ignoring it in your `.hgignore`.  You could be ignoring a pattern that matches directories above `temp`, or all the files or directories below `temp`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Might want to post that as an alternative answer (the only tracks files bit).